# HTML5 - hgroup - linebrak <br> doesnt validate?

Tags: html

Im wondering why using linebreak 
 inside HTML5 - tag  doesnt validate according to w3 standards? 
Can i use some other tag to use between headings instead?

Example which gives an error in http://validator.w3.org:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title>HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>

<hgroup>
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <br>

    <h2>heading 2</h2>
</hgroup>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<br>` should be in inline context, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put nothing else then `<h1>` - `<h6>` within `<hgroup>`!

You have to use CSS styling to give a bit more space between consecutive headers within `<hgroup>` element.

Comment: Do i have any other options than line-height to control the vertical placement of h1 to h6 inside hgroup?

Comment: You can use `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: Ok - got it - im using a reset CSS where headings are "display: inline" which disables vertical use of margin - my mistake!

Comment: However it would be nice to able to use br inside hgroup - but it probably kills the intention of HTML5 simple and fast browser-reading. Ok - br cant be used in hgroup. I was just wondering why - thx for answers

Answer (score 1):

The only valid tags you can put inside an `<hgroup>` are from `<h1>` to `<h6>` and hence `<br />` is an invalid tag here

[image]